# Assign value to array from plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have the following code in Oracle Forms detail block

```
BEGIN
v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
Go_block('detail_block');
first_record;
--some if condition
WHILE :SYSTEM.last_record != 'TRUE' LOOP        
next_record;     
if(:detail_block.product_no = v_product_no) then  
 -- other condtions

end if;

END LOOP;
```

I would like to store `v_product_no` into a some kind of collection object so that I could compare with value of `:detail_block.product_no`.

How can I do this?

**Edit 1**

`product_no` will have values such as `K1BATTERY`, `K2BATTERY`, `ZCATBATEERY` etc.
So if `K1BATTERY` is same as `:detail_block.product_no` then proceed with next condition

**Edit 2**

```
Go_block('detail_block');
v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
v_products(v_product_no) := 1;

first_record;

WHILE :SYSTEM.last_record != 'TRUE' LOOP            

    if(v_products.exists(v_product_no)) then
        alert('duplicate');  
            end if;     
    END LOOP;

END if;
```

**Edit 3**

```
Go_block('detail_block');
v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
v_products(v_product_no) := 1;

    first_record;

    -- condition 


    WHILE :SYSTEM.last_record = 'FALSE' LOOP    
        next_record;        
        v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
        if(v_products.exists(v_product_no)) then
            alert('duplicate'); 
             else
      v_products(v_product_no) := 1; 

            end if;

        END LOOP;

    END if;
```

Comment: Do you really need a collection object? You can create a package spec and have it store the value if it's a scalar value. Also why not just store it into local block variable?

Comment: @Sathya My intention is if `product_no` is getting repeated, then I would like to have another if condition to be evaluated in same detail block. Having `v_product_no` stored in `varchar2` is not helping to compare values in multi record block. Thanks

Comment: You don't need a collection type to store a scalar value. Declare another variable locally and assign the value, it could be used in the scope of the session, as it is a local variable.

Comment: @LalitKumarB If I declare as a local variable, how can I compare all the items in multi record block against current record's item value?

Comment: Perhaps it is not clear. What kind of values assigned by `:detail_block.product_no`? Please show an example, I will try to reproduce what you want.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I have edited my question, hope I have made it clear.

Comment: You're not assigning `v_product_no` in the loop, so it remains the same throughout the loop

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you need to do exactly? Why do you need the variable to be a collection? What are you actually trying to compare?

Comment: If you want to assign the list of values to `product_no` as varying-IN list, then you could split them and compare.

Comment: @Sathya Could you show an example as how to check if there is a repetition of product_no in multiple record block? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pl/sql associative array to store already processed values.

```
declare
  type t_processed is table of number(1) index by varchar2(100);
  v_product_no varchar2(100); --hold the current value
  v_products t_processed;     --hold all processed values as keys
begin
  v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
  v_products(v_product_no) := 1; --create entry (v_product_no, 1)
  ...
  --later in while
  v_product_no := :detail_block.product_no;
  if(v_products.exists(v_product_no)) then --entry exists
  -- other conditions
  else
      v_products(v_product_no) := 1; --create entry (v_product_no, 1)
  end if;
...
```

Comment: I have tried this, however it inside while loop for checking exists condition, it goes into a infinite loop.

Comment: @Polppan this is an issue in your loop, not in this general construct

Comment: I have included my code snippet in my question as Edit 2

Comment: Yes, it does require an user action.

Comment: I have cases where I there are no duplicate entry of prod_no, still it shows duplicate record as alert. I have included code snippet as Edit 3.

Comment: @Polppan move `first_record;` directly after `Go_block`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having [Varying IN list of values](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/varying-in-list-of-values-in-where-clause/) in **`v_product_no`** variable.

You could do it in following way,

**Test# 1**

```
SQL> var product_no VARCHAR2(1000)
SQL> exec :product_no := 'K1BATTERY'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_product_no VARCHAR2(1000);
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_product_no := 'K1BATTERY, K2BATTERY, ZCATBATEERY';
  5    IF :product_no IN (trim(regexp_substr(v_product_no, '[^,]+'))) THEN
  6      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOUND A MATCH');
  7    ELSE
  8      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO MATCH FOUND');
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
FOUND A MATCH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Test# 2**

```
SQL> var product_no VARCHAR2(1000)
SQL> exec :product_no := 'ABCD'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_product_no VARCHAR2(1000);
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_product_no := 'K1BATTERY, K2BATTERY, ZCATBATEERY';
  5    IF :product_no IN (trim(regexp_substr(v_product_no, '[^,]+'))) THEN
  6      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOUND A MATCH');
  7    ELSE
  8      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO MATCH FOUND');
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
NO MATCH FOUND

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: this is a risk because you do not know the count of the records and you can run out of variable size